# Use Base64-encoding for wait handle inside UserData

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I have UserData with this syntax:

```
  UserData:
    Fn::Base64: !Sub |
      <script>
      .........
      cfn-signal.exe ${MyWaitHandle}
      </script>
```

The problem is that `${MyWaitHandle}` needs to be encoded with Base64, and I don't know how to do that. I tried with `${Base64:MyWaitHandle}` but I got a validation error.

I'm migrating from JSON to YAML, and the original JSON had `"cfn-signal.exe  ",  {"Fn::Base64" : {"Ref" : "MyWaitHandle"}}`.

How do I recreate that inside the `!Sub |` syntax?

Comment: Doesn't CFN do that automatically?  I use waits in YAML, and here is my code in the UserData section:

`cfn-signal -e $0 -r AMI -i waitedforami "${WaitHandlePendingAMI}"`

I have never needed to do any encoding.

Comment: Hm, I'll try that.